# Does changing max-pool-size require server restart in jboss-7.1.1 form UI or Command line?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I want to change max-pool-size at runtime in jboss-7.1.1, but without restart it cannot be updated. Althouth the changed value is showing in Profile.
In runtime available count it is not chnaged.
Also it's not showing in console message or anywhere else that a restart is required like if I change pool-prefill then it says that a reload is required.
Please guide for the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is no uniform answer to if your configuration change requires reload or restart.

It is dependent on many factors, first and most important being does attribute/resource you are modifying support runtime changes?
Second is related to the state/runtime mode of the server you are in.

Maybe some other change before your current one already put server in "reload-required" or "restart-required" state.

In short, if result of operation includes "reload-required" or "restart-required" flag, than you should reload/restart the server.

Just some note on what reload-required and restart-required states are.
In most cases (99%+) of attributes/resources only reload is required, which means you only need issue "reload" operation in CLI, instead of doing full shutdown of jvm and starting it again.

restart-required does actually mean you need to shut down the jvm and restart the server to properly apply the changes. This is very rare situation.

On general topic, we aim with every new version of WildFly to have more and more runtime changeable attributes, so if one attribute was not runtime changeable in previous version it could be in current. Only way to tell is to either look at metadata (:read-resource-description) or inspect the result of the operation.

Comment: Isn't there any documentation for this (Specific to Jboss-as-7.x.x Final)? I have got some information from this URL https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Operations_Network/3.1/html/Dev_Complete_Resource_Reference/JBossAS7-JBossAS7_Standalone_Server-Datasources_-Standalone-.html. But this doesn't include restart required(Y/N) for all parameters!